# SimpleSchema error: After filtering out keys not in the schema, your modifier is now empty

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, simple-schema

I created new SimpleSchema for my collection. Collection definition & schema:

[GIST](https://gist.github.com/CandyOgre/c767032f34eeb78323becb3aa7ec83b3)

After calling this method from client:

```
export const setEventInvitationStatus = new ValidatedMethod({
 name: 'events.updateParticipantStatus',

 mixins: [LoggedInMixin],

 checkLoggedInError: {
  error: 'notLogged',
 },

 validate: new SimpleSchema({
  eventId: { type: String },
  inviteTo: { type: String },
  newStatus: { type: String },
 }).validator(),

 run({ eventId, inviteTo, newStatus }) {
  Events.update(
    {  '_id': eventId, 'participants.userId': inviteTo },
   {
    $set: { 'participants.$.inviteStatus': newStatus },
   });
 },
});
```

I get this error:

```
Exception while invoking method 'events.updateParticipantStatus' { stack: 'Error: After filtering out keys not in the schema, your modifier is now empty\n    at [object Object].doValidate (packages/aldeed_collection2-core/lib/collection2.js:374:1)\n    at [object Object].Mongo.Collection.(anonymous function) [as update] (packages/aldeed_collection2-core/lib/collection2.js:173:1)\n    at [object Object].run (imports/api/events/server/methods.js:101:10)\n    at [object Object].LoggedInMixin.methodOptions.run (packages/tunifight:loggedin-mixin/loggedin-mixin.js:28:16)\n    at ValidatedMethod._execute (packages/mdg:validated-method/validated-method.js:93:12)\n    at [object Object].ValidatedMethod.connection.methods._connection$methods.(anonymous function) (packages/mdg:validated-method/validated-method.js:54:23)\n    at [object Object].methodMap.(anonymous function) (packages/meteorhacks_kadira/lib/hijack/wrap_session.js:164:1)\n    at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1704:12)\n    at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:711:19\n    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)',
```

What I do wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to include your array of participants in the schema:

```
validate: new SimpleSchema({
  eventId: { type: String },
  inviteTo: { type: String },
  newStatus: { type: String },
  participants: { type: [Object]}, // array of objects
 }).validator()
```

Comment: Okay, I`ll try that. Must I include this validation to all methods, operating with collection?

Comment: I'm not sure if that needs to be there if you are not touching the participants key. In any case you should organize your code so that you only declare your schema once and not all over the place.